# Scala Play framework 2.2 - How to get information about a users loginstatus in template

Tags: scala, templates, session-variables, playframework-2.2

I have the following use-case. I implemented a very simple authentication in my play app which adds a session cookie if a user logs in (See code below).

This code works fine so far. What I want to achieve now is to check in my main template if a user is logged in or not and display login/logout elements on the page according to the user status.

How can I achieve this in the most elegant way?

I have found sources where people access the session variables directly from the template with play <= 2.1. It seems like this method doesn't work for 2.2 anymore and is deprecated?
Do I have to pass a boolean value in every action to the template to define if a user is logged in??

**Wrapper Action**

```
case class Authenticated[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] {

  def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    if (request.session.get("user").getOrElse("").equals("user")) { 
      action(request) 
    } else {
      Future.successful(Redirect("/login").withSession(("returnUrl", request.path)))
    }
  }

  lazy val parser = action.parser
}
```

**Submit Part of Login Controller**

```
def submit = Action { implicit request =>
  loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => Ok(html.login.form(errors)),
    requestUser => {
      val user: String = Play.current.configuration.getString("fillable.user").getOrElse("")
      val password: String = Play.current.configuration.getString("fillable.password").getOrElse("")
      if (requestUser.name.equals(user) && requestUser.pw.equals(password))
        Redirect(request.session.get("returnUrl").getOrElse("/")).withSession(session + ("user" -> requestUser.name) - "returnUrl")
      else
        Ok(html.login.form(loginForm, "error", Messages("error.wrongCredentials")))
    })
}
```

**Example Controller Action where Authentication is needed**

```
def submit = Authenticated {
  Action.async { implicit request =>
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I found out now is that if the Controller Action uses an implicit request(like the one in my question above) I can use that request and therefore the session in my template if I add this to the head of the template:

`(implicit request: Request[Any])`

I am not sure if this is a good approach so I am happy if someone can approve it.